# Array Search in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I currently try to learn some Haskell to improve my overall programming skills. To practice, I implement the C course exercises that I very familiar with. One is this:

> Write a function that finds an array (needle) inside of another array (haystack). Return the index where the first match starts. If it cannot be found, return `-1`.

So in C, this is implemented using a couple of loops:

```
int array_find(char *hay, char *nee, int hay_len, int nee_len) {
    int hay_idx, nee_idx;
    for (hay_idx = 0; hay_idx < hay_len - nee_len; hay_idx++) {
        for (nee_idx = 0; nee_idx < nee_len; nee_idx++) {
            if (hay[hay_idx + nee_idx] != nee[nee_idx]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nee_idx == nee_len) {
            return hay_idx;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The following is my attempt in Haskell. I made comments which probably state the obvious for Haskell experts but it should make my reasoning clear.

```
-- Public function, searches the haystack for a needle and returns the index
-- (zero-based).
arraySearch :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe Int
arraySearch h n = arraySearchNext (arraySearchBegin h n 0) h n 0

-- Searches the haystack starting from the next position if the last search has
-- failed.
arraySearchNext :: (Eq a) => Maybe Int -> [a] -> [a] -> Int -> Maybe Int
-- The previous search has found something, so that is the first occurence of
-- the needle.
arraySearchNext (Just i) _ _ _ = Just i
-- The previous search has not given us anything but we are out of haystack.
-- Therefore nothing could be found.
arraySearchNext Nothing [] _ _ = Nothing
-- The previous search has not found anything but there is some haystack left.
-- We will try the search again by shifting by one and then shift again.
arraySearchNext Nothing (h:hs) n i =
    arraySearchNext (arraySearchBegin hs n (i + 1)) hs n (i + 1)

-- Looks whether the needle can be found at the beginning of the haystack.
arraySearchBegin :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int -> Maybe Int
-- In case we managed to finish the needle, we must have found something.
arraySearchBegin _ [] i = Just i
-- In case the haystack is empty, but the needle is not (pattern above), we
-- have not found anything.
arraySearchBegin [] _ _ = Nothing
-- There is still some haystack and needle left. If the first element each
-- matches, we must go on. Otherwise this won't be a match.
arraySearchBegin (h:hs) (n:ns) i
    | h == n        = arraySearchBegin hs ns i
    | otherwise     = Nothing

main = print $ arraySearch [1..10] [5..6]
```

Since there are so many lines and I have a bunch of helper functions, I wonder whether there is some better way‽

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Long time no see, by the way. Does your real/own code use the comments inbetween?

Comment: @Zeta: I think I would only have one comment block in front of every function. The comments in between seem to make it harder to read the actual code. I have only done this here to explain my thinking because my code might look incomprehensible to a Haskell expert.

Answer (score 2):

You use explicit recursion, which is fun, but not always necessary. `arraySearchBegin` can be expressed with `zipWith` and `and`, for example:

```
arraySearchBegin :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> b -> Maybe b
arraySearchBegin hs ns k
  | and (zipWith (==) hs ns) = Just k
  | otherwise                = Nothing
```

But that's still to explicit. `Data.List` contains `isPrefixOf`, which is exactly what we need:

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)

arraySearchBegin :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> b -> Maybe b
arraySearchBegin hs ns k
  | ns `isPrefixOf` hs = Just k
  | otherwise          = Nothing
```

That being said, `arraySearchBegin`'s name is misleading. `[a]` is a linked list, not an array. We should probably rename it, but we won't use it in the final variant of `arraySearch`.

Next, we don't need the `Maybe Int` in `arraySearchNext`:

```
arraySearchNext :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int -> Maybe Int
arraySearchNext []         ns _ = Nothing
arraySearchNext hss@(_:hs) ns i
  | ns `isPrefixOf` hss = Just i
  | otherwise           = arraySearchNext hs ns (i + 1)
```

We can stop as soon as our needle is a prefix of our haystack. However, we're basically checking all tails of `hss` here. And there is again a function in `Data.List` that yields those `tails` for us:

```
ghci> import Data.List
ghci> tails [1..5]
[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5],[]]
```

We therefore just check which one is the first list in `tails haystack` that can be prefixed by `needle`. If we `zip` the indexes with the `tails` we're able to write `arraySearch`  as a list comprehension:

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)
import Data.List (isPrefixOf, tails)

search :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe Int
search hs ns = listToMaybe [ idx | (idx, hss) <- zip [0..] tails hs
                                 , ns `isPrefixOf` hss
                           ]
```

But `Data.List` contains `findIndex :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe Int`, which brings us to:

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf, tails, findIndex)

search :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe Int
search hs ns = findIndex (ns `isPrefixOf`) (tails hs)
```

This however needs knowledge of the standard library. So how do you find those functions if you don't know them yet? Welcome to [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). We can find `findIndex` by searching for [`(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe Int`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20Bool%29%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20Maybe%20Int), `isPrefixOf` by [`Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Eq%20a%20%3D%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20Bool) and `tails` by [`[a] -> [[a]]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5Ba%5D%5D).

If we didn't have any of those helpers, your code would be fine, except for the strange explicit result in `arraySearchNext`'s first argument. That was too complex, as you will stop as soon as you find a `Just` either way.